# Function does not return value in kdb/q

Tags: kdb

I have a function declaration in kdb/q:

```
q)func_demo:{[time1;time2] select from t where time within(time1 time2)}
```

where the datatype for time is `v`. And the query works perfectly.

I pass two time into the function:

```
q)func_demo[13:00:00 13:00:02]
```

But there is no table showing in the console, and it gives me something like:

```
{[time1;time2] select from tt where tp_time within(time1 time2)}[13:00:00 13:00:02]
```

Could someone gives me some hints  how to deal with this issue? is that because I don't convert `13:00:00` to type 'v' when I pass in the parameters?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the parameters as @emc211 has suggested; however there is a problem with the function you are using  `(time1 time2)`

```
{[time1;time2] select from tt where tp_time within(time1 time2)}[13:00:00;13:00:02]
```

It should be  `(time1;time2)`  - semicolon (`;`) after `time1`

```
{[time1;time2] select from tt where tp_time within(time1; time2)}[13:00:00;13:00:02]
```

Explanation :

```
time1:13:00:00
time2:13:00:02
```

this is similar to `time1@time2`

```
q)(time1 time2)
'type
[0]  (time1 time2)
```

To use the `time1` and `time2` as list :

```
q)(time1;time2)
13:00:00 13:00:02
```

If you are using the actual values then no need to specify the `;` for the similar type of elements.

```
(time1;time2)~(13:00:00 13:00:02)
1b
```

Answer (score 3):

Your function takes two parameters time1 and time2
in your line `q)func_demo[13:00:00 13:00:02]` you are only passing the function one parameter which is a list of times.

Do you mean to pass `q)func_demo[13:00:00;13:00:02]`

What you get returned is actually of function projection. Code below to explain

```
q)f:{x+y}
q)f[2;2]
4
q)f[2 2]
{x+y}[2 2]
q)proj:f[2 2]
q)proj 10 100
12 102
q)proj
{x+y}[2 2]
```

Comment: thanks. but if i pass q)func_demo[13:00:00;13:00:02], it gives me ERROR: 'type (wrong type)

Comment: tp_time    v(datatype)  s(attribute) 
instrument_id  i(datatype)